# constructor and the assignment operator

Tags: c++

Can I write a copy constructor through the assignment operator? Like this:

```
A::A(const A * a) {
    *this = a;
}

A &A::operator=(const A * a) {
    delete str;
    str = new char[strlen(a->str)+1];
    strcpy(str, a->str);
    return *this;

}
```

Still want to clarify whether if I do A * a in the above example, because samples from different sites A & a. C This pops up a question that should return the assignment operator:

```
A &A::operator=(const A * a)
```

or

```
A * A::operator=(const A * a)
```

General question: Is my code right above?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What does your compiler issues as error message? `*this` is of type `A`, `a` is of type `const A*`.

Comment: are you trying to reimplement std::string?

Comment: 1. Why not `std::string` 2. If you have a good answer for 1, atleast use `std::unique_ptr` if C++11 is an option.

Comment: `new char[strlen(a->str)+1]` looks like oranges with peanut butter.

Comment: I have to question why you're implementing an assignment operator and "copy"-ctor (which isn't, btw) for a rhs-pointer in the first place. Any particular reason you're not just doing it *correctly* (either by const-reference or value param and copy/sway idiom)?

Comment: Extracting, this is done the other way around. The assignment operator (both copy and move) is defined in terms of the appropriate constructor by using the copy-swap idiom. As it is, if `new` throws an exception, your original `str` is gone and that object is left hanging.

Comment: @AndrewArnold nothing happened. seems to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to make `str` be a `std::string` and then you don't need to write your own copy constructor OR copy assignment operator.

But let's say you *have to* write your own for non-obvious reasons you can't share with us.

In that case, a typical approach to provide some exception safety is to implement a nothrow swap function, and then implement copy assignment in terms of copy construction + swap (the opposite of what you're proposing, but provides much better exception safety for the copy assignment)

Comment: +1 If the OP reads one thing on this page, let it be this answer; *please*.

Comment: @Mark B can give an example?

Comment: @yejep: It's called "copy-and-swap idiom". http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap

Answer (score 0):

Both of them have different signature:

```
A::A(const A &a);
A &A::operator=(const A &a);
```

What you are writing is not copy constructor nor assignment operator.

Look for copy-and-swap idiom, this is what allows you to write copy assignment in terms or copy construction.

Comment: If I write as you then get an error that can not be converted * to &

Comment: Think. a becomes an object of type A inside functions then so you cannot use a-> to access fields. You have to change it to a.. Two dots intended.

Comment: Here's a look http://pastebin.com/zsL7asaW It seems to be working. It is correctly written?